# How to decode encoded escape characters in Java?

Tags: java, encoding, decoding

Consider the following JSON Object,

```
{
     "params":[{
                  "name":"param1",
                   "value" : "%0A"
               },
               {
                  "name":"param2",
                   "value" : "%09"
               },
                {
                  "name":"param3",
                   "value" : "hello%09"
               }]
}
```

If you notice, the value fields are all encoded form of escape characters (in this case, \n, \t, hello\t respectively). Assume I can retrieve these values as params.getValue(). Now how can I decode them and get the actual values i.e \n, \t, hello\t in my example ?

Comment: by adding (basically the same) escape character. just check this print statement: System.out.println("\\n \n end");

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) from apache commons-lang.

Comment: No need for an external library. Just use `URLDecoder.decode`